# Visual studio code ошибка при сохранении файла

Tags: visual-studio-code

У меня настроен autosave. И не могу сохранить изменения из-за ошибки:
**"Не удалось сохранить "имя файла": Произошла системная ошибка (EBUSY: resource busy or locked, open "локальный адрес файла")"**

И самое странное, она исчезает спустя некоторое время. То есть дальше всё сохраняется.